# Given that something holds for an arbitrary union of sets, does it also hold for the lim sup?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

In a problem I am working on, I want to say the following:

Since $\int f \chi_{[0, 1] \setminus \cup_{i = l}^{\infty}I_{n_i}} = 0$ for each $l$,  $\int f \chi_{[0, 1] \setminus \cap_{l = 1}^{\infty}\cup_{i = l}^{\infty}I_{n_i}} = 0$

Is this true? Note that the $I_{n_i}$ are all disjoint open sub-intervals of $[0, 1]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may help to change your notation around a bit: write $E_l = [0, 1] \setminus \cup_{i = l}^{\infty}I_{n_i} = \cap_{i=l}^\infty [0,1] \setminus I_i$. Then $E_1 \subset E_2 \subset E_3 \subset \cdots$

Write $E = \cup_{l=1}^\infty E_l$. Then $\chi_{E_l}(x) \nearrow \chi_{E}(x)$ for all $x$. As long as $f \ge 0$ you can use the monotone convergence theorem to find that $$\int f \chi_E = \lim_{l \to \infty} \int f \chi_{E_l} = 0.$$

If $f$ belongs to $L^1$ you can apply the preceding result to the positive and negative parts separately.

Comment: Wow... I don't know what I was thinking. Thank you.